# Trying to print imported list using OOP. Not much luck. New to OOP

Tags: python, oop, csv

I don't strongly understand using OOP. I am trying to create a printer class that I can call whenever needed but I am not having much luck. The bigger program was easy enough using procedural programming but this would be much more efficient.

```
class data():
    def __init__(self):
        import os
        import csv
        self.new_list = []
        os.chdir('C:\Users\U2970\Documents\ArcGIS')
        with open('roadlog_intersection_export_02_18_2014_2.csv', 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                self.new_list.append(row)

    def printer(self):
        print self.new_list

out = data()
out.printer()
```

Comment: What makes you think this would be more efficient? Also is efficiency a real concern in this project?

Comment: I would recommend going with the procedural approach. Here are some general suggestions:

 1. Mention that you are using Python 2, not Python 3, in your SO question.
 2. Use a better name for the class other than "data", and capitalize the name.
 3. Import the modules at the top of the file, not inside a method or function.
 4. There's no point in creating a class for this, just have this code in a function. (Explaining why would be an extended discussion on OOP, but trust me. Also, efficiency isn't really a worry in a one-off task like this, but code readability is. Keep It Simple.)

Comment: It's not clear what your actual problem is, not why you think this is more efficient than the procedural version

Comment: Please describe what you are expecting versus what the script is actually doing (including any errors). Once you point out what the actual problem is (*i.e.*, what the script isn't doing) someone will be able to help you more effectively.

Comment: Python 2. Well this is a small part of a much bigger program but i tried to shrink down the first issue i was dealing with to be more succinct. Im sorry it is a bit terse in what the question offers. This is more of just an example.

Comment: otherwise right now when i try to run the code it just sits with the curser blinking. What I am really trying to do is create a printer class to call for many lines of code below. Sorry the indentation stinks in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having some trouble understanding exactly what your problem is, but I can give you some feedback on your code and oop in general.

Firstly, you generally don't want to hard-code values within an object as that will make it only useful for a very limited application. I would suggest including a `load()` function that loads in a file, and then a `printer()` function that will then print whatever is currently loaded.

This would look something like this:

```
class data(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.current_list = None

    def load_file(self, filename):
        self.current_list = list(csv.reader(open(filename, 'r')))

    def printer(self):
        print(self.current_list)
```

You could use it like this:

```
out = data()
data.load('C:\Users\U2970\Documents\ArcGIS\roadlog_intersection_export_02_18_2014_2.csv')
data.printer()
```

Also look into using [qGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) instead of ArcGIS.

If you want to do this as a function instead (there's no real reason to write such a shallow wrapper) You could just do something like this:

```
def print_csv(filename):
    print list(csv.reader(open(filename, 'r')))

print_csv('C:\Users\U2970\Documents\ArcGIS\roadlog_intersection_export_02_18_2014_2.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks alot for that code Stater that should be a big help. I'll try make that work. So can i make a class call for printing or should I just stick to using a function? Seems like that could go either way.

Comment: @montana_geek Personally I would suggest using a function, or re-evaluating why you're doing this in the first place. Printing out big csv's isn't something you should probably be doing in any case, let alone repeatedly.

Comment: So i would reset the file on every class call? Interesting. Well each function within the program is printing out a piece of the .csv according to different conditions. I wouldnt print the whole thing its about 235,000 lines!

Comment: Thanks a ton Slator ill try out your suggestions!